# lambda expression to select single row from parent table where join table object value contains specific object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lambda

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I searched and can not find my scenario.

I have a "parent" table called Tournaments and a Players table which houses participants of tournaments.  This is a many to many relationship because I can have multiple tournaments and the same players (or more or less) can participate in each tournament.

I have created a join table for the purpose of allowing my many-to-many relationship.

my objects look like this:
TournamentEntity.cs

```
public class TournamentEntity : IInt32Identity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<TournamentPlayers> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

TournamentPlayers.cs (this is my join entity)

```
    public class TournamentPlayers
        {
            public int TournamentId { get; set; }
            public TournamentEntity Tournament { get; set; }
            public int PlayerId { get; set; }
            public PlayerEntity Player { get; set; }
        }
```

PlayerEntity.cs

```
public class PlayerEntity : IInt32Identity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<TournamentPlayers> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to return a list and/or a single instance of TournamentEntity with a simple lambda expression from a single PlayerEntity passed into my method.

example method:

```
public async Task<TournamentEntity> GetTournamentByTournamentParticipant(PlayerEntity tournamentParticipant)
    {
            return await EntityDbSet
                .Where(x => x.Participants.Contains) // this is where I'm a bit lost on how to link to "tournamentParticipant"
                ...
                .Include(x => x.Participants)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.Player)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
return await EntityDbSet
                .Where(x => x.Participants.Any(p => p.PlayerId == tournamentParticipant.Id))
                .Include(x => x.Participants)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.Player)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```